# Speed of iterating through 1-dimensional vs 2-dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I was reading a post on how iterating through a 2-dimesional array horizontally is faster than vertically because of the way the data is stored(See:[Fastest way to loop through a 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997212/fastest-way-to-loop-through-a-2d-array)). That made sense when I read the answer but it got me wondering what the difference was between 2 and 1 dimensional arrays. Is there any speed difference in iterating 1-dimension vs 2-dimension arrays with the same number of cells?

Comment: On a related note, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6631081/1003855

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Java, there are many more factors and more overhead with arrays. As arrays are objects, `int[][]` is an array of array objects of `ints`. This may make horizontal iteration faster than vertical if hotspot optimizes or caches the array access.

For one vs two dimensional, one-dimensional would be faster as it's an array lookup and a primitive vs an array lookup, a dereference of a reference of an array object, and then a lookup in *that* array.

However, such microoptimization is not necessarily the best use of *your* time, as there are likely better places for improvements.

Comment: it's marginally faster

Comment: @SamIam marginally is an overstatement in this case.