# efficiency of loop through a 2d array horizontally or vertically

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I read an article in stackoverflow posted 4 years ago, see here:
[Fastest way to loop through a 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997212/fastest-way-to-loop-through-a-2d-array)
Almost every answer agreed that scan horizontally will faster. I wrote a short Java program to check this, it turned out not the case. I choose 400x400 matrix. The time for scan horizontally is 6 and the time for scan vertically is 3. I checked other sizes of matrix. It also turned out scan vertically is faster. Do I miss something or is it indeed the case?

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        int row=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int column=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int[][] bigarray=new int[row][column];

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
            bigarray[i][j]=Math.abs(i-j)-Math.abs(i-j);


    long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("scan horizentally time is: ");
    System.out.println(totalTime);

    int[][] bigarray1=new int[row][column];

    long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
            bigarray1[i][j]=Math.abs(i-j)-Math.abs(i-j);


    long endTime1   = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime1 = endTime1 - startTime1;
    System.out.println("scan vertically time is: ");
    System.out.println(totalTime1);

}

}
```

Comment: First, to measure time, you should use [`System.nanoTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) instead `System.currentTimeMillis` since the former is more accurate. Second, refer to this link to have a better understanding about micro benchmarking: http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/1065197

Comment: I am a bit curious about your results with large matrices; 400x400 is in favor of vertically on my machine, but the advantage slips rapidly: 4000x4000 is a very different story.

Comment: Yes, if I check 4000x4000 or bigger matrix, then the horizontal scan is faster. That's very interesting!

Comment: I changed the code by nano time, the result is similar to before. For small or median size matrix, horizontal scan is slower. The situation changes if use big enough matrix.

Comment: swap the cases in the code and check if you get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

For the horizontal version, you could optimize the code:

```
for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    int[] rowArray = bigarray[i];
    for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
        rowArray[j]=Math.abs(i-j)-Math.abs(i-j);
```

I wouldn't be surprised if the first test is always slower with your test setup. Java takes a lot of warmup time... A better test setup might be to have two separate programs, and to take a few warmup loops before taking the time...